# Running one dashboard by multiple users simultaneously

Tags: widget, databricks, dashboard

I have a databricks dashboard with different widgets. It has two three graph that change based on user inputs (widgets). I want to share this dashboard with several users to run it separately and simultaneously. However, when one user changes the widget value, the other users see the changes and the graphs are updated. Is there any way a user runs the dashboard separately and see the visualization according to its own input, and not the other users' inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I am aware of for this problem is to clone the notebook/dashboard (File --> Clone from the main menu) for each user that needs it. This is not idea for maintenance, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not the solution though, as the users cannot see the latest changes of the main notebook.

Comment: @Enayat yes, I agree, but I haven't found any other solution. If you do please post an answer !